# Kotlin- Coroutines read file

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope, withcontext

Main function:

```
val users = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{readFile()}.toString()
```

readFile:

```
suspend fun readFile(): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    .............
    return@withContext fullString
}
```

I'm not sure if my code is good, because im creating 2 coroutines. first one is by using CoroutineScope (Dispatchers.IO) and second one is in readfile using withContext. what is the best approach to this?

Read file using coroutines

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating two coroutines. The `launch` call creates a coroutine. The `withContext` call doesn't create a new coroutine, it just modifies the conditions of the currently running coroutine that calls the function that uses it.

Note, your `users` variable is launching an asynchronous coroutine, and then calling `toString()` on the returned Job, which is likely not what you intended. You cannot get the result of a coroutine from outside that coroutine unless you use `async` instead of `launch` and call `await()` on the returned Deferred. But you can only call `await()` on it if you are inside a coroutine.